# performance degrades when adding several worldpoints instances to children

Tags: helix-3d-toolkit

we've successfully implemented a demo project based on the earth examples in the helix 3d toolkit and we are creating an effect where the world rotates by using a timer and AddRotateForce on the camera controller.  The problem we are having is that when more than a couple hundred worldpoints added to the HelixViewport3D children collection, the rotation effect slows down to the point of not being usable.

is there a better way to add additional children the the world sphere without affecting performance dramatically?